# Enable/disable Button on TextChanged event of TextBox in WPF by XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

There are TextBox and Button controls in WPF:

```
<TextBox Name="BackUpTextBox" />
<Button  Name="BackUpSave" Content="Save" />
```

Button BackUpSave must be enabled if a text of BackUpTextBox is changed.
I know how to do that by BackUpTextBox TextChanged event by C# code.
But is there a way to enable/disable button by XAML notation?

Comment: I just wonder am I the first for several years since XAML who asked this seems to me simple question: to enable Button if TextBox's text is changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that via `EventTrigger`. Wrap both controls in `StackPanel` so that `TextChanged` *events routed upto its parent StackPanel*.

And in that case enable Button by setting `IsEnabled` to `True`.

```
<StackPanel>
   <TextBox x:Name="BackUpTextBox"/>
   <Button x:Name="BackUpSave" Content="Save" IsEnabled="False"/>
   <StackPanel.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.TextChanged">
         <BeginStoryboard>
           <Storyboard>
            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="BackUpSave">
                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
           </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
     </EventTrigger>
     <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
       <BeginStoryboard>
         <Storyboard>
          <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="BackUpSave">
                 <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
          </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
         </Storyboard>
       </BeginStoryboard>
     </EventTrigger>
     <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
       <BeginStoryboard>
         <Storyboard>
          <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="BackUpSave">
                 <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
          </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
         </Storyboard>
       </BeginStoryboard>
     </EventTrigger>
  </StackPanel.Triggers>
</StackPanel>
```

---

**UPDATE**

In case you want to *disable button on button click again*, add another event handler for `Button.Click` and set it to disable from that. I have updated the xaml code for that.

---

**UPDATE 2**

> Solution looks such cumbersome that I have big doubt if it worth
>   compared to just setting IsEnabled property in Initial, TextChanged
>   and Click events. Am I missed something that XAML style more
>   preferable these days?

Yes, i have to agree with that *XAML only solutions are sometimes cumbersome which can easily be done using code behind*. Specifically in your case it could have been done simply by hooking onto some events and more importantly that's ***not violating any MVVM rules since you are doing view specific things in code behind***. So, i see no harm in doing ti from code behind.

XAML only solutions i would generally prefer *in cases where i want to store my XAML loosely in some text file and want to load that at runtime using `XamlReader.Load()`*.

And as i mentioned animation has higher precedence over local values setter for Dependency property. So, once `TextChanged` event gets raised value gets set to true and any further change to that property from code behind won't work.

But anyhow you can change that from code behind by setting it via animation (will post here just for completeness of answer and might help others who stumble upon this post). This is how you do it from code behind:

```
private void Button_BackUpSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   EnableDisableBackUpSaveButton(false);
}

private void EnableDisableBackUpSaveButton(bool value)
{
   BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames animation = 
                              new BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
   DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame keyFrame = new DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame(value, 
                           KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0)));
   animation.KeyFrames.Add(keyFrame);
   BackUpSave.BeginAnimation(Button.IsEnabledProperty, animation);
}
```

Now, in XAML you can only have single XAML trigger on `TextChanged`.

Comment: The button BackUpSave is always switched to Enabled state even if in click event it is turned Disabled.

Comment: As per your question - `Button BackUpSave must be enabled if a text of BackUpTextBox is changed`. So, that means you want it to be enabled when text changes. Where you are setting it to be disabled?

Comment: Rohit, it is changed in MainWindow constructor:

Comment: But you want to enable it always whenever text changed. Right?

Comment: Rohit, it is changed in MainWindow constructor:
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();     
      BackUpSave.IsEnabled = false;
    }
and in Click event: 
     private void Button_BackUpSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { ...
      BackUpSave.IsEnabled = false;      
    }

Comment: Rohit, yes, I want it enabled whenever text is changed.

Comment: I have updated the answer to disable it on button click. Hope that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Why isEnabled property of this button doesn't work in XAML, MainWindow, click event and I guess nowhere? Initial state of this button must be disabled because initially text is not chenged. Is it possible to disable button in XAML definition like: IsEnabled="false"?

Comment: Initial property of button in answer is false. `<Button x:Name="BackUpSave" Content="Save" IsEnabled="False"/>`

Comment: So it will be disabled on load. Solution not working for you?

Comment: Despite initial property IsEnabled="False" this button is always initially enabled at run time. How to disable it initially?

Comment: You must have set it to true somewhere. Or may be TextChanged event is getting raised on load. It's working for me in small sample i created.

Comment: Initially in MainWindow the TextBox is set to some text from app.config file. For example: BackUpTextBox.Text = "C:\". Which is definitely triggering TextChanged event.

Comment: Actually issue is Storyboard setter has higher precedence over local value so if value is set by storyboard then any local change won't be reflected. That's why you seeing this issue. As a workaround you can have storyboard on loaded event as well which will set it to false. I will update in answer.

Comment: Updated in answer and you can read more about dependency property precedence order [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you Rohit. Now it is working. I'll mark you answer as acceptable. But the solution looks such cumbersome that I have big doubt if it worth compared to just setting IsEnabled property in Initial, TextChanged and Click events. Am I missed something that XAML style more preferable these days?

Comment: `Am I missed something that XAML style more preferable these days?` - I have updated an answer for this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a data trigger:

```
<TextBox Name="BackUpTextBox" />
    <Button  Name="BackUpSave" Content="Save">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=BackUpTextBox, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=BackUpTextBox, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" Value="">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

In a real-world application though you wouldn't do this in XAML because there'd be no way to test this behavior in your unit tests.

Comment: The button BackUpSave is never switched to Disabled state.

Comment: Mark, can you update your solution to working condition?