# Enable button based on button click at same position

Tags: c#, wpf

I have WPF form consisting of buttons and texts. I want to enable button "B" after processing "X"(returning bool)  is done. "X" starts on button click "A" and want to replace/disable button "A" by Button "B" at the same position once the processing is complete.

**How can I trigger that behavior?**

Comment: pls provide a further/better explantion, and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Welcome. Your question is essentially a set of _requirements_.  We're not here to write code for you sadly.  See [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470556/enable-disable-button-on-textchanged-event-of-textbox-in-wpf-by-xaml but it defaults text to  null but how to trigger the same for button click.

Comment: I am so sorry starting to learn WPF and C#.

Comment: You can have the same button by replacing its label , and call different functionalities based on label value . Try putting your question in a more elaborative  manner

Answer (score 0):

I have written same code in java, so as same you can write in WPF

```
private boolean onClick;
onClick=false;
if(onClick=!onClick)
{
    //write code here on click
}
else {      
    //again on click it get disable 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, I know how to do in JAVA but it seems WPF little different and new to me.

Comment: This doesn't address the question.  OP is talking about c# and WPF so not sure how mentioning Java will help